# How to make vlookups in Excel select the EXACT match instead of the first occurence of matching digits

Tags: excel, vlookup

Is there a way to make an excel vlookup use the entire number rather than the first set of matching digits?  I am vlookup-ing a concatenated number that has several occurrences of the first 10 digits.  When I vlookup 49272480517 from the below table, I get back the first occurrence of a 4927248051 match instead of the full concatenated number 49272480517.

```
RefDoc.No.  DocLi   concat
4927248051  1   49272480511
4927248051  2   49272480512
4927248051  3   49272480513
4927248051  4   49272480514
4927248051  5   49272480515
4927248051  6   49272480516
4927248051  7   49272480517
```

Comment: Normally using a fourth parameter of 0 or FALSE will force Excel to find an exact match. If you're already doing that, can you show us the formula you are using, and some sample data from the other data set.

Comment: I'm curious how are you pulling off a vlookup with value `49272480517` from the last column and getting a value from the first column. Vlookup works left-to-right. I suspect you're making some bad assumptions about how vlookup works. Please share your formula.

Comment: Step back from Vlookup. Maybe that is not the best function in this scenario. Describe what you want to achieve, regardless of the formula you think you need.

Answer (score 0):

If your concatenated strings are in `column C` and your lookup value is in `H1`, use the below formula,

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(H1,C:C,0),1)
```